# How to generate llvm bitcode for large programs with many source code files and a huge Makefile (e.g. memcached)?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have my pass that I tested on toy programs and now I want to run it on large programs, many of which are open source programs like memcached. Such programs have their own Makefile and a complicated compilation procedure. I want to generate a bitcode file for such programs to let my pass work on them. Help and suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're pass is doing you can:

- Build with [LTO](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html): adding -flto to the CFLAGS and building your application with your own built linker plugin is quite seamless from a build system point of view. However it requires some understand about how to setup LTO.
- Build with your own built clang: adding statically your pass to the LLVM pipeline and use your own built clang. Depending on the build system, exporting CC/CXX environment variable pointing to your installed clang should be enough.
- Build by loading your pass dynamically into clang, for example this is what [Polly](http://polly.llvm.org/example_load_Polly_into_clang.html) is (optionally) doing.

Comment: Thanks Joky! So I need to do one of these 3 options? Are there any existing examples for the first 2 options?

Comment: I don't think so, but option 2 is not hard to setup, maybe the least of these. If you have a pass, just add it at the right place in PassManagerBuilder.cpp and build clang.

Comment: So what I did is editing the Makefile and putting clang and the relevant flags in place to replace gcc/g++ so that my pass works on the code. My pass instruments the program by adding a function calls, that function is in another .c file. But I get undefined reference error from clang. I posted this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650417/clang-linking-error-undefined-reference-to-function-calls-added-by-llvm-pass

Can you take a look? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you add -emit-llvm to your clang flags, it will emit BC files instead of object files or LL files instead of assembly.

You'll likely have to modify the makefile some more bit that should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you think I will have to modify those program's existing Makefile and replace gcc with clang manually with the bc flag? Any existing tools?