# Clang Linking error: undefined reference to function calls added by LLVM pass

Tags: makefile, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

So I am following this tutorial https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html to make a pass that instruments a program by adding calls to an external function (which is logop in rtlib.c). But unlike the tutorial I am trying to instrument a larger code-base which is masstree: https://github.com/kohler/masstree-beta.

So as instructed for masstree I run ./configure first but then I edit the generated Makefile to use clang (instead of gcc/g++) and run my pass. I also add rtlib.c in the masstree source files so that it gets converted to rtlib.o with the rest of the masstree source files. Here is the relevant part of the modified Makefile with my changes highlighted with an arrow (I also added the $(rtlib) to link it with other .o files to generate executables):

```
AR = ar
rtlib = rtlib.o  <===
CC2 = clang -w -v -Xclang -load -Xclang  /.../llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/lib/SkeletonPass.so `llvm-config --cflags` 
CXX2 = clang++ -v -w -Xclang -load -Xclang /.../llvm-3.4/Release+Asserts/lib/SkeletonPass.so -std=c++11 `llvm-config --cppflags --libs --cflags --cxxflags core --ldflags` <===
CC = clang -v <===
CXX = clang++ -v -std=c++11 <===
CPPFLAGS = 
CXXFLAGS = -g -W -Wall -O3
DEPSDIR := .deps
DEPCFLAGS = -MD -MF $(DEPSDIR)/$*.d -MP
ifeq ($(strip $(MEMMGR)), )
  MEMMGR = 
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(KEYSWAP)), )
  CPPFLAGS += -DKEYSWAP
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(NOPREFETCH)), )
  CPPFLAGS += -DNOPREFETCH
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(NOSUPERPAGE)), )
  CPPFLAGS += -DNOSUPERPAGE
endif
LIBS =  -lpthread -lm
LDFLAGS = 

all: test_atomics mtd mtclient mttest

%.o: %.c config.h $(DEPSDIR)/stamp
    $(CXX2) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEPCFLAGS) -include config.h -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cc config.h $(DEPSDIR)/stamp
    $(CXX2) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEPCFLAGS) -include config.h -c -o $@ $<

%.S: %.o
    objdump -S $< > $@

libjson.a: json.o string.o straccum.o str.o msgpack.o \
    clp.o kvrandom.o compiler.o memdebug.o kvthread.o
    @/bin/rm -f $@
    $(AR) cru $@ $^

KVTREES = query_masstree.o \
    value_string.o value_array.o value_versioned_array.o \
    string_slice.o

mtd: mtd.o log.o checkpoint.o file.o misc.o $(rtlib) $(KVTREES) \
    kvio.o libjson.a
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

mtclient: mtclient.o misc.o testrunner.o kvio.o $(rtlib) libjson.a
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

mttest: mttest.o misc.o checkpoint.o $(rtlib) $(KVTREES) testrunner.o \
    kvio.o libjson.a
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

test_string: test_string.o string.o $(rtlib) straccum.o compiler.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

test_atomics: test_atomics.o string.o straccum.o kvrandom.o $(rtlib) \
    json.o compiler.o kvio.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

jsontest: jsontest.o string.o straccum.o json.o compiler.o $(rtlib)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

msgpacktest: msgpacktest.o string.o straccum.o json.o compiler.o msgpack.o $(rtlib)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

scantest: scantest.o compiler.o misc.o $(rtlib) $(KVTREES) libjson.a
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(MEMMGR) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

I use CC2 and CXX2 to generate the instrumented .o files while CC and CXX to link them into executables. Here is the error I get when I run make:

> mtd.o: In function `main':
>   /home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:730: undefined reference to`logop'
>   /home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:730: undefined reference to `logop'
>   /home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:732: undefined reference to`logop'
>   /home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:732: undefined reference to `logop'
>   /home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:736: undefined reference to`logop'
>   mtd.o:/home/.../masstree-beta-master/mtd.cc:736: more undefined references to `logop' follow
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [mtd] Error 1.

Any Idea on why is the reference to my function logop (which is in rtlib.c) undefined even though I add rtlib.o in the linking part to generate executables?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible ideas:
1) Put rtlib.o at the end of the object files for linking.
2) Build rtlib.o with a C++ compiler.
3) Check that rtlib.o is exporting the function (objdump -t).
4) Check the symbol in mtd.o matches the exported symbol in rtlib.o.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I examined mtd.o using objdump -S and couldn't find a call to my external function logop(int, int, char). This confuses me as I thought the error `undefined reference to logop' ` meant that a function call is inserted but the linker cannot find the definition of the function logop, moreover the lines 730 and 732 etc are the lined where I expect logop to be inserted.

Comment: @Brian, any thoughts after my last comment?

Comment: Prelinking, the assembly may not have calls to the external function, as its address is not yet known.  Instead, there are generic call instructions: `callq  14` (will become gets() in my quick test).  And I can see, using objdump -t, that there is an undefined symbol in the object file for gets.

Comment: @Brian, I am now actually thinking of breaking down the linking process and link mtd.o to rtlib.o to make mtd-intermediate.o first then link mtd-intermediate.o and the other needed .o files to make mtd executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol exported were not the same. I checked using `nm --format sysv  *file.o*` to make sure the symbols exported from rtlib.o and wherever they are used is the same.